# How to initialize an array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, initialization

I am initializing an array like this:

```
public class Array {

    int data[] = new int[10]; 
    /** Creates a new instance of Array */
    public Array() {
        data[10] = {10,20,30,40,50,60,71,80,90,91};
    }     
}
```

NetBeans points to an error at this line:

```
data[10] = {10,20,30,40,50,60,71,80,90,91};
```

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: You could replace that "int data[] = new int[10]" by "int data[]". You are wasting memory there.

Answer (score 731, accepted):

```
data[10] = {10,20,30,40,50,60,71,80,90,91};
```

The above is not correct (syntax error). It means you are assigning an array to `data[10]` which can hold just an element.

If you want to initialize an array, try using [Array Initializer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6):

```
int[] data = {10,20,30,40,50,60,71,80,90,91};

// or

int[] data;
data = new int[] {10,20,30,40,50,60,71,80,90,91};
```

Notice the difference between the two declarations. When assigning a new array to a declared variable, `new` must be used.

Even if you correct the syntax, accessing `data[10]` is still incorrect (You can only access `data[0]` to `data[9]` because index of arrays in Java is 0-based). Accessing `data[10]` will throw an [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html).

Comment: Actually, the primary reason it is incorrect is that it is a syntax error!  The AIOB would only happen if the syntax was acceptable.

Comment: Could you please help me, If I declare an array like this: `public static void product(int[] array){ int[] productArray = new int[array.length];` and want to set all the values of `productArray` **zero**, what should I write? (I think I should write a loop and set all values to zero, is there any better way to do this?)

Comment: @Hengameh: It's initialized to 0 by default. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2154340/1000655

Answer (score 47):

Try

```
data = new int[] {10,20,30,40,50,60,71,80,90,91 };
```

Comment: +1. You have an extra opening brace. One can also write: data[0] = 10; data[1] = 20; .... after int data[] = new int[10], but it is too much code and it will end up doing the same thing.

Answer (score 30):

When you create an array of size 10 it allocated 10 slots but from 0 to 9.
This for loop might help you see that a little better.

```
public class Array {
    int[] data = new int[10]; 
    /** Creates a new instance of an int Array */
    public Array() {
        for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            data[i] = i*10;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

You can do:

```
int[] data = {10,20,30,40,50,60,71,80,90,91};
```

Comment: I'm wondering what value this adds on top of the accepted answer from 5 years prior.

Answer (score 13):

Syntax

```
 Datatype[] variable = new Datatype[] { value1,value2.... }

 Datatype variable[]  = new Datatype[] { value1,value2.... }
```

Example :

```
int [] points = new int[]{ 1,2,3,4 };
```

Answer (score 7):

**Rather than learning un-Official websites learn from oracle website**

link follows:[Click here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

***You can find Initialization as well as declaration with full description ***

```
int n; // size of array here 10
int[] a = new int[n];
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
{
    a[i] = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine()); // using Scanner class
}
```

**Input**:
10//array size
10
20
30
40
50
60
71
80
90
91

**Displaying data:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) 
{
    System.out.println(a[i] + " ");
}
```

**Output:**
10 20 30 40 50 60 71 80 90 91

Comment: OP clearly is trying to assign a bunch of values at once. Your response doesn't acknowledge this fact.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot initialize an array like that. In addition to what others have suggested, you can do :

```
data[0] = 10;
data[1] = 20;
...
data[9] = 91;
```

Answer (score 4):

***If you want to initialize an array in a constructor,
you can't use those array initializer like.***

```
data= {10,20,30,40,50,60,71,80,90,91};
```

Just change it to

```
data = new int[] {10,20,30,40,50,60,71,80,90,91};
```

You don't have to specify the size with `data[10] = new int[] { 10,...,91}`
Just declare the property / field with `int[] data;` and initialize it like above.
The corrected version of your code would look like the following:

```
public class Array {

    int[] data;

    public Array() {
        data = new int[] {10,20,30,40,50,60,71,80,90,91};
    }

}
```

As you see the bracket are empty. There isn't any need to tell the size between the brackets, because the initialization and its size are specified by the count of the elements between the curly brackets.

Answer (score 3):

you are trying to set the 10th element of the array to the array try

```
data = new int[] {10,20,30,40,50,60,71,80,90,91};
```

FTFY

Answer (score 1):

```java
int myArray2[] = new int[3];
int[] myArray = new int[3];
int[] intArray = {13, 14, 15};
int[] intArray = new int[]{7, 8, 9};
int[] intArray = IntStream.range(1, 11).toArray();
int[] intArray = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10).toArray();
int[] intArray = IntStream.of(6, 2, 4, 5, 7).toArray();
int[] intArray = IntStream.of(6, 2, 4, 5, 7).sorted().toArray();
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this will work:

```
public class Array {

    int data[] = new int[10]; 
    /* Creates a new instance of Array */
    public Array() {
        data= {10,20,30,40,50,60,71,80,90,91};
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this  differ from the question? Please extend your answer!

Comment: Array initializer aren't allowed in constructors !!!!
You should at least test your proposals, before posting them...