# Any shortcut to initialize all array elements to zero?

Tags: java

In `C/C++` I used to do

```
int arr[10] = {0};
```

...to initialize all my array elements to 0.

Is there a similar shortcut in Java?

I want to avoid using the loop, is it possible?

```
int arr[] = new int[10];
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = 0;
}
```

Comment: java.util.Arrays.fill() int[] arr = new int[10];
and int arr[10] = {0}; all use internal loops.

Answer (score 657, accepted):

A default value of 0 for arrays of integral types is guaranteed by the [language spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5):

> Each class variable, instance variable, or array component is initialized with a *default value* when it is created (§15.9, §15.10) [...] For type `int`, the default value is zero, that is, `0`.

If you want to initialize an one-dimensional array to a different value, you can use [java.util.Arrays.fill()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill(int[],%20int)) (which will of course use a loop internally).

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt Was helpful answer to me. Would that have the same cost of doing it comparing to for loop?

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥıλɐɯ: you can look at the source code, it comes with the JDK. It's exactly the same, the method consists of nothing but a perfectly normal, straightforward for loop.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt What about the values of a local 2-dimensional array? Does that fall under "array component?"

Comment: `Arrays.fill` doesn't necessarily use a loop.

Comment: @NateS: can you give an example of a Java implementation that doesn't?

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt I can't, but `Arrays.fill` doesn't guarantee how it is implemented. It's not unreasonable to think a JVM could use `memcpy`.

Comment: @NateS: That's what the JVM might very well use after JIT-compiling the Java loop, but on the API implementation level that would, in fact, be very unreasonable because it would require a native method, which comes with its own considerable overhead.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt The API level is the `Arrays.fill` method declaration, how it is implemented is unspecified. A JVM could special case the method without using JNI. For example, `Math.cos` may look like a StrictMath JNI call in JDK sources, but most JVMs replace the Java method with an intrinsic.

Comment: The Oracle implementation of Arrays.fill is slightly different from the basic for loop in that it caches the array length.

Answer (score 130):

While the other answers are correct (int array values are by default initialized to 0), if you wanted to explicitly do so (say for example if you wanted an array filled with the value 42), you can use the fill() method of the [Arrays](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill%28int[],%20int%29) class:

```
int [] myarray = new int[num_elts];
Arrays.fill(myarray, 42);
```

Or if you're a fan of 1-liners, you can use the [`Collections.nCopies()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#nCopies%28int,%20T%29) routine:

```
Integer[] arr = Collections.nCopies(3, 42).toArray(new Integer[0]);
```

Would give arr the value:

```
[42, 42, 42]
```

(though it's `Integer`, and not `int`, if you need the primitive type you could defer to the [Apache Commons `ArrayUtils.toPrimitive()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#toPrimitive%28java.lang.Integer[]%29) routine:

```
int [] primarr = ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(arr);
```

Comment: One-liners are good, but `List<Integer>` to `Integer[]` to `int[]`? That's a bit convoluted.

Comment: @dhardy Sure, but that's why there's the 2-line version in the answer as well (if you're concerned about the "convoluted" factor).

Comment: initializing 2d array with `Arrays.fill` method is creating problem and error occurs.

Answer (score 52):

In java all elements(primitive integer types `byte` `short`, `int`, `long`) are initialised to 0 by default. You can save the loop.

Comment: I suppose this holds for the primitive types?!

Comment: Primitive java types, like int, are not initialized.

Comment: @tfb785: This is wrong. As stated above by Michael Borgwardt: primitive integer types (short, int, long) are initialized to 0.

Comment: Yes, array of java primitives like int[] are initiated with 0. No, one java primitive type is not initiated with 0.

Comment: Ok, to be precise: primitive class members (be it static or not) are initialized with 0. Local variables are not.

Answer (score 25):

How it Reduces the Performance of your application....? Read Following.

In Java Language Specification the **Default / Initial Value** for any Object can be given as Follows.

For type **byte**, the **default value** is **zero**, that is, the value of (byte) is **0**.

For type **short**, the **default value** is **zero**, that is, the value of (short) is **0**.

For type **int**, the **default value** is **zero**, that is, **0**.

For type **long**, the **default value** is **zero**, that is, **0L**.

For type **float**, the **default value** is **positive zero**, that is, **0.0f**.

For type **double**, the **default value** is **positive zero**, that is, **0.0d**.

For type **char**, the **default value** is the **null** character, that is, '**\u0000**'.

For type **boolean**, the **default value** is **false**.

For **all reference types**, the **default value** is **null**.

By Considering all this you don't need to initialize with zero values for the array elements because by default all array elements are 0 for int array.

Because An **array** is a container object that holds a fixed number of values of a single type. 
Now the Type of array for you is **int** so consider the default value for all array elements will be **automatically 0** Because it is **holding int type**.

Now **consider** the **array** for **String type** so that all array elements has **default value** is **null**.

**Why don't do that......?**

you can assign null value by using loop as you suggest in your Question.

```
int arr[] = new int[10];
for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    arr[i] = 0;
```

**But if you do so then it will an useless loss of machine cycle.
and if you use in your application where you have many arrays and you do that for each array then it will affect the Application Performance up-to considerable level.**

The more use of machine cycle **==>** More time to Process the data **==> Output time will be significantly increase**. so that your application data processing can be considered as a low level(Slow up-to some Level).

Answer (score 18):

You can save the loop, initialization is already made to 0. Even for a local variable.

But please correct the place where you place the brackets, for readability (recognized best-practice):

```
int[] arr = new int[10];
```

Answer (score 15):

If you are using Float or Integer then you can assign default value like this ...

```
Integer[] data = new Integer[20];
Arrays.fill(data,new Integer(0));
```

Answer (score 6):

You can create a new empty array with your existing array size, and you can assign back them to your array. This may faster than other.
Snipet:

```
package com.array.zero;
public class ArrayZero {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Your array with data
    int[] yourArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    //Creating same sized array with 0
    int[] tempArray = new int[yourArray.length];
    Assigning temp array to replace values by zero [0]
    yourArray = tempArray;

    //testing the array size and value to be zero
    for (int item : yourArray) {
        System.out.println(item);
    }
}
}
```

Result :

```
0
0
0
0
0    
0
0
0
0
```

Answer (score 2):

Initialization is not require in case of zero because default value of int in Java is zero.
For values other than zero `java.util.Arrays` provides a number of options, simplest one is fill method.

```
int[] arr = new int[5];
Arrays.fill(arr, -1);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));  //[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1 ]

int [] arr = new int[5];
// fill value 1 from index 0, inclusive, to index 3, exclusive
Arrays.fill(arr, 0, 3, -1 )
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)); // [-1, -1, -1, 0, 0]
```

We can also use Arrays.setAll() if we want to fill value on condition basis:

```
int[] array = new int[20];
Arrays.setAll(array, p -> p > 10 ? -1 : p);

int[] arr = new int[5];
Arrays.setAll(arr, i -> i);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));   // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

you can simply do the following

```
 int[] arrayOfZeros= new int[SizeVar];
```

Answer (score 1):

The int values are already zero after initialization, as everyone has mentioned. If you have a situation where you actually do need to set array values to zero and want to optimize that, use `System.arraycopy`:

```
static private int[] zeros = new float[64];
...
int[] values = ...
if (zeros.length < values.length) zeros = new int[values.length];
System.arraycopy(zeros, 0, values, 0, values.length);
```

This uses `memcpy` under the covers in most or all JRE implementations. Note the use of a static like this is safe even with multiple threads, since the worst case is multiple threads reallocate `zeros` concurrently, which doesn't hurt anything.

You could also use `Arrays.fill` as some others have mentioned. `Arrays.fill` *could* use `memcpy` in a smart JVM, but is probably just a Java loop and the bounds checking that entails.

Benchmark your optimizations, of course.

Answer (score 1):

In c/cpp there is no shortcut but to initialize all the arrays with the zero subscript.Ex:

```
  int arr[10] = {0};
```

But in java there is a magic tool called Arrays.fill() which will fill all the values in an array with the integer of your choice.Ex:

```
  import java.util.Arrays;

    public class Main
    {
      public static void main(String[] args)
       {
         int ar[] = {2, 2, 1, 8, 3, 2, 2, 4, 2};
         Arrays.fill(ar, 10);
         System.out.println("Array completely filled" +                          
            " with 10\n" + Arrays.toString(ar));
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You defined it correctly in your question, it is nearly the same as for C++. All you need to do for the primitive data type is to initialize the array. Default values are for int 0.

```
int[] intArray = new int[10];
```

Answer (score 0):

declare the array as instance variable in the class i.e. out of every method and JVM will give it 0 as default value. You need not to worry anymore

Answer (score 0):

Yes, int values in an array are initialized to zero. But you are not guaranteed this. Oracle documentation states that this is a bad coding practice.

Comment: According to the Java Language specification, section [15.10.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10.2), if an array is created with an array creation exception that does not provide initial values, then all the elements of the array are initialized to the default value for the array's component type - i.e. 0 in the case of char[]. This is a guarantee; I'd be quite surprised of Oracle considered relying on it to be a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach by using lambda above java 8

```
 Arrays.stream(new Integer[nodelist.size()]).map(e -> 
 Integer.MAX_VALUE).toArray(Integer[]::new);
```

Answer (score -6):

```
    int a=7, b=7 ,c=0,d=0;
    int dizi[][]=new int[a][b];
    for(int i=0;i<a;i++){
        for(int q=d;q<b;q++){
            dizi[i][q]=c;               
            System.out.print(dizi[i][q]);
            c++;
        }

        c-=b+1;
        System.out.println();               
    }
```

result 
    0123456
    -1012345
    -2-101234
    -3-2-10123
    -4-3-2-1012
    -5-4-3-2-101
    -6-5-4-3-2-10