# Modifiying variables that only differ in the index

Tags: java

I was programming right now and I wanted to modify the value of ten variables that shared their name but had a different index at the end. For example:

```
    int number1
    int number2
    int number3
    int number4
    ...
```

If I want to put the same value in all the variables, for example initialize them at 0, Is there any way to do this with a loop in which I only have to modify the index?

Something like this:

```
    for(int i=0;i<=10;i++) {
       number"i" = 0; }
```

Probably it is a silly question, but I can't find the solution. Thank you very much :)

Comment: You shall replace your variables with an array.

Comment: some tutorials exist about java and can be very useful.

Comment: Oh, I didn't think about using an Array. That makes sense. It was a very stupid question, sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment, go for an array.

From the loop given in your question, it seems as if you want 10 numbers. In that case something like

```
int[] arNum = new int[10];
```

should declare the array.

To initialize the array with all `0`, try

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    arNum[i] = 0;
```

Note: Array indexes always start at `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use an array:

```
int[] arr = new int[10];
```

To be clear:

> Each class variable, instance variable, or array component is
>   initialized with a default value when it is created (§15.9, §15.10)
>   [...] For type int, the default value is zero, that is, 0.

Taken from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5). You might also want to take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154251/any-shortcut-to-initialize-all-array-elements-to-zero).