# Incrementing and decrementing in expandable listview

Tags: android

I have created the expandablelisview.If i click the plus imageview in child items the value of count is increased by 1. Initially the count value is 0 for all child item.If i click the plus in 1st row,the count value increased from 0 to 1.After that,i clicked the 2nd row means the count value increased from 1 to 2.I want to increase the count value as 0 to 1 in not 1 to 2 in 2nd row`

```
public class ExpandListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Group> groups;
    ArrayList<Child> ch_list=new ArrayList<Child>();

    Integer count=0;

    public class ViewHolder {

        TextView tv ;
        ImageView food_image;
        ImageView minus,plus ;
         TextView item_count;

    }


    public ExpandListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Group> groups) {
        this.context = context;
        this.groups = groups;

    }


    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        ArrayList<Child> chList = groups.get(groupPosition).getItems();
        return chList.get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final Child child = (Child) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);



        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.detail_list, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.type);
            viewHolder.food_image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.food_image);
            viewHolder.minus = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.minus);
            viewHolder.plus = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.plus);
            viewHolder.item_count = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.count);


            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);


        }
        else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        viewHolder.tv.setText(child.getName().toString());


        final ViewHolder finalViewHolder = viewHolder;
        viewHolder.plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                count=count+1;
                finalViewHolder.item_count.setText(count.toString());
            }
        });




        final ViewHolder finalViewHolder1 = viewHolder;
        viewHolder.minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                count=count-1;
                finalViewHolder1.item_count.setText(count.toString());   //Key -> String.valueOf(position) and Value -> int count
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public  int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        ArrayList<Child> chList = groups.get(groupPosition).getItems();
        return chList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return groups.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return groups.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Group group = (Group) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.group_item, null);
        }
        TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.group_name);
        tv.setText(group.getName());
        ExpandableListView eLV = (ExpandableListView) parent;
        int count = getGroupCount();
                          if(count<1){

                             eLV.expandGroup(groupPosition);
                             // eLV.setGroupIndicator(null);
                          }


        return convertView;
    }



    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Logcat error`

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: abservetech.com.foodapp, PID: 1807
                                                                       android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x1
                                                                           at android.content.res.Resources.getResourcePackageName(Resources.java:1871)
                                                                           at android.content.res.SPRDResources.getThemeResources(SPRDResources.java:94)
                                                                           at android.content.res.SPRDResources.getText(SPRDResources.java:155)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getText(ResourcesWrapper.java:52)
                                                                           at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3927)
                                                                           at abservetech.com.foodapp.ExpandListAdapter$1.onClick(ExpandListAdapter.java:99)
                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4446)
                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18437)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5372)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:970)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Define the count variable not as a global variable in the class but as a local one in getChildView. You could display it inside each row or whatever. But that way it will be unique to each row and not global to the adapter.

EDIT:

Create a Integer Array global inside your adapter

```
int[] myIntegerArray = new int[size];
```

integers array are by default initiated to 0 as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154251/any-shortcut-to-initialize-all-array-elements-to-zero).
You now just need to do inside getChildView onClickListener:

```
myIntegerArray[childPosition] += 1 
finalViewHolder.item_count.setText(Integer.toString(myIntegerArray[childPosition]));
```

Comment: I just told you, create the variable inside the getChildView function. With something like Integer count = 0; It should do the trick.

Comment: its work but if scroll the list the value get recycle

Comment: Indeed I forgot about recycle. Try to create a global array with the size of the max item in your list. Then inside getChildView access the array at the view position. That should workaround the problem of the recycle

Comment: can u explain me with simple codes.I can't understand what ur telling

Comment: If i do like that means it shows error.i have posted  my logcat error

Comment: Yes silly mistake on my side. But let's interpret the logcat to find the mistake:  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3927). Means problem on setText line. Then can't find ressource id means that compiler is looking for an ID, but it should not cause it should be a string. I forgot to add Integer.toString(myIntegerArray[childPosition]) which transform into string. I edit with it

Comment: new int[size]; which size?

Comment: The size you want for your list. Could be 10 100 1000. What you want. You can change it for a constant.

Comment: Accept the answer if the problem is fixed, otherwise comment your problem :)

Comment: i have tried this now its working  but when i increased the row value in group1(1st child)means that same value will increased in group2(1st child)

Comment: Then use groupPosition and not childPosition