# Java equivalent to python array initialization

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array, initialization

What is the equivalent in Java to this in Python?

```
array_name = [0 for i in range(5)]
```

Specifically, I want to create a 2 dimensional Java ArrayList and initialize each value as 0. This is what I was thinking, in semi-psuedocode, following Python, but it obviously doesn't work:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> grid = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>() {{
    (add(Arrays.asList(0 for i : ROWS) for j : COLUMNS);
}};
```

Where ROWS and COLUMNS are constants defined elsewhere. In the end, I want a 2D ArrayList, with sizes given by the ROWS and COLUMNS constants, and each value initialized as 0. Is there a way to do this?

And ArrayLists don't allow primitive types as the generic type (like the primitive int). Then having the reference type doesn't have a default of 0 since it is an object. So any other questions concerning the initialization of an array to 0 that have to do with the primitive int don't answer mine.

Comment: to create an array of integers for example initializing, java does with zeros

Comment: @Dev.that's true for ``int[]`` but not for ``ArrayList<Integer>``.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any shortcut to initialize all array elements to zero?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154251/any-shortcut-to-initialize-all-array-elements-to-zero)

Comment: Like @f1sh says, the possible duplicate is right for the primitive int and array, not my situation with the Integer object for an ArrayList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To initialize a `ArrayList` with zeros could make use of the method [nCopies](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#nCopies%28int,%20T%29)

```
    int ROWS =3;
    int COLUMNS=3;
    List<List<Integer>> twoDimArray = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();//declaration
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS ; i++) { // cant rows 
        twoDimArray.add(Collections.nCopies(COLUMNS, new Integer(0)));
        //initialized to zero the number of columns you want
    }

    /* Print  */

    for (List<Integer> list : twoDimArray) {
        System.out.println(list);
    }
```

> In the example use the List <> to replace ArrayList as it is much
>   better ... and for references to this review
>   [Type List vs type ArrayList in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279030/type-list-vs-type-arraylist-in-java)

Comment: What exactly does the "cant" mean in the two variables declared at the top?

Comment: Is the number of rows and columns of your multidimensional array

Comment: So pretty much cantRows is ROWS and cantColumns is COLUMNS in my code?

Comment: If it is, change my answer to that is more understandable

Comment: `Integer.valueOf(0)` may save heap than `new Integer(0)`

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> grid = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i ++) {
    ArrayList<Integer> row = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j ++) {
        row.add(Integer.valueOf(0));
    }
    grid.add(row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In java 8, the equivalent would be:

```
List<List<Integer>> grid = Stream.generate(() -> Collections.nCopies(COLUMNS, 0))
                                 .limit(ROWS)
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note that you cannot modify the list returned by `Collections.nCopies`, so a better alternative might be:

```
List<List<Integer>> grid = Stream.generate(() -> new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(COLUMNS, 0)))
                                 .limit(ROWS)
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you really need the type of the grid to be `ArrayList<ArrayList>`, you do:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> grid = Stream.generate(() -> new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(COLUMNS, 0)))
                                           .limit(ROWS)
                                           .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```