# differentiate the two codes

Tags: java, reflection

Was going through a question on so,and this thing confused me

```
 getDeclaredConstructor(new Class[]{String.class,Integer.class})
```

but this thing also works

```
getDeclaredConstructor(String.class,Integer.class)
```

then why we use the above one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do to initialize array in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938101/how-do-to-initialize-array-in-java)

Comment: Also, look into var-args.

Comment: sorry I made a syntax error,I meant this

Comment: Also, you should consider accepting answers in your questions if they helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use both and the behavior is the same. I guess it's just for convenience.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html

> The three periods after the final parameter's type indicate that the
>   final argument **may be passed as an array or as a sequence of
>   arguments**. Varargs can be used only in the final argument position.