# Null Pointer Exception error while creating array of files

Tags: java, arrays, file-io

Inside the for loop, depending on if condition, files need to be created every time. While executing the code, `NullPointerException` pops up.

```
    File[] tempDir=null; 
    for(  )
    {
    if(condition){
        try {
            tempDir[l]=new File(tempFileName);
            if(l==0){
                tempDir[l++].mkdir();
                /*code*/
            }
            if (!tempDir[l].exists()){
                tempDir[l++].mkdir();
                /*code*/
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't initialize the `tempDir` array.

Change

```
File[] tempDir=null;
```

to

```
File[] tempDir=new File[somePositiveInteger];
```

`tempDir[l]` would throw a `NullPointerException` if `tempDir` is null.

Comment: public static void copyFileContents(File source, File dest)throws IOException{ ....  }                                                    try { tempDir[l]=new File(tempFileName);                              if(l==0){
      tempDir[l++].mkdir();
       copyFileContents(new File("D:\\gokul\\Auto"+"\\"+fileName+".txt"),new File("D:\\gokul\\Dest"+"\\"+tempFileName+"\\"+fileName+".txt")); } /*Showing Null Pointer Exception*/

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing your File array to null here ,

```
File[] tempDir=null;
```

So you are getting **NPE** when you are trying to find the first element of the File Array here ,

```
tempDir[l]=new File(tempFileName); // tempDir[l] represents the element at position 1
```

So you should declare the size of the array withe positive value as Eran pointed out in his answer . Also have a look at [How to initialize an array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938101/how-do-i-initialize-an-array-in-java)