# What is the syntax error in this program?

Tags: java

I know there is a syntax error here, but why?

```
public class Practice_1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[3][3] Array={{11,22,33},{44,55,66},{77,88,99}};

        for (int i=0 ; i<3 ; i++)
        {
            for (int j=0 ; j<3 ; j++)
            {

              System.out.println("Array["+i+"]["+j+"]  store value is"+Array[i][j]);

            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to initialize an array in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938101/how-to-initialize-an-array-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you don't specify the size of the array dimensions in the type.  Here, the dimensions are implied in the array initializer anyway.  Remove the 3s from the declaration of the array.

```
int[][] Array={{11,22,33},{44,55,66},{77,88,99}};
```

As an aside, in Java, variables are typically declared to start with a lowercase character.  It's not an error, but `Array` would typically be declared with the name `array`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[3][3] Array={{11,22,33},{44,55,66},{77,88,99}};   //wrong way to declare array
```

change to

```
int[][] Array={{11,22,33},{44,55,66},{77,88,99}};
```

[Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

> Note:Please follow java naming convention start variable with lower
>   case or camelCase

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in your array definition. Instead of using

```
int[3][3] Array={{11,22,33},{44,55,66},{77,88,99}};
```

You should be using

```
int Array[3][3] = {{11,22,33},{44,55,66},{77,88,99}};
```

In java, you must place an array's size ***on it's name definition***, rather than the type definition. In this case, a size could be omitted altogether, but following your current design, that will work.

In addition, your variable names, by convention, are normally *camel-cased*, with first words being lower cased, and following words being upper cased. Normally, class names are written as you wrote your `Array` variable, which could lead to confusion.