# What is the signature of method which gets four double numbers and returns a double array?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, return, double

I'm a bloody Java beginner and need some help.

I was wondering what the signature of a public method called "feld" looks like which gets four double numbers and returns a double array.

My exercise says "return a double array". But can i even do that or do i need to return values of my Array? My code won't work at all.

```
public double [] feld (double q, double w, double e, double r){
            double [] A = {q;w;e;r};
            return A;
}
```

Comment: replace the `;` in between the braces with `,`

Comment: I like your user name :-)

Comment: You should start writing your code with an IDE like eclipse etc. because it will show you these issues as you write your code.

Comment: i use eclipse and i didn't get it although i checkt out eclipse error warning xD next time i know better

Answer (score 4):

Change `double [] A = {q;w;e;r};` to `double [] A = new double[] {q, w, e, r};`

Answer (score 1):

**try this**

```
public double [] feld (double q, double w, double e, double r){
        return new double[]{q,w,e,r};
}
```

**Your version** doesn't work, because the *syntax* was **incorrect**.There's a whole question about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938101/how-to-initialize-an-array-in-java?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score -1):

Do you want to print? İf you want :

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    double [] a = feld(1,2,3,4);
    for ( double i : a){
        System.out.print(i);
    }
} 

public static double [] feld (double q, double w, double e, double r){
    double [] A = {q,w,e,r};
    return A;}
```

Comment: This would print "1234". Doesn't look that good for four individual numbers.

Comment: The answer is not directly related to the original question since its author is not asking about printing.