# How and where to initialize global array of EditText and Button in android Studio using Java

Tags: android

I have created my first calculator app but to reduce the size and to simplify the code i want to create an `EditText` as global variable and latter a `Button` array also as global variable.
For now when I define and initialize the `EditText` array outside of the method the app crashes on the start.

But when I define the array outside the method and initialize it inside of the method I get error of array initialization not allowed here. what to do? sample code will be appreciated please.

**Case-1 (app crashes)**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    EditText[] editList = {(EditText) findViewById(R.id.decValue), (EditText) findViewById(R.id.octValue), (EditText) findViewById(R.id.hexValue), (EditText) findViewById(R.id.hexValue),(EditText) findViewById(R.id.binValue)};
    ..
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ..
    }
}
```

**Case-2 (error of cannot initialize array here)**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    EditText[] editList;
    ..
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ..
    editList = {(EditText) findViewById(R.id.decValue), (EditText) findViewById(R.id.octValue), (EditText) findViewById(R.id.hexValue), (EditText) findViewById(R.id.hexValue),(EditText) findViewById(R.id.binValue)};
    }
}
```

Comment: It makes no sense to make any view "global". Any view only has relevance inside the parent that holds it (eg. `Activity` or `Fragment`). Using `findViewById()` will only find one resource they are not interchangeable.

Comment: @Barns How do I define and initialize a 'EditText' array variable that is accessible by all the methods inside the 'Activity' lets say 'MainActivity.java' using an array. It's is required as I have created methods for performing different task e.g. disabling/enabling 'Buttons' and 'EditText', performing calculations, changing colours etc.

Comment: You mean class variable instead of global variable! Class variables are accessible throughout the class. But, global variables are accessible throughout the entire app... which would lead to quite a few errors if they were to reference a `TextView` or similar view.

Comment: @Barns yes you are correct, I mean the class variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Case 1**

You're using an instance initializer so your list is initialized before MainActivity's constructor is called, and before onCreate() -> setContentView(), which means there is no UI at that point.

**Case 2**

You can only use shorthand array initialization syntax when declaring the member variable.

Replace it with `new EditText[]{...}`.

**Advice**

I would use [ButterKnife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) library. It makes view binding easier and you can also group multiple views into a list which is what you're trying to achieve.

Add dependency

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
  annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
}
```

In your activity:

```
@BindViews({R.id.first_name, R.id.middle_name, R.id.last_name})
List<EditText> nameViews;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //...
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
}
```

That's it. Looks much more readable.

Apply an action to all views in a list:

```
ButterKnife.apply(list, (view, index) -> {
    //your action for view
});
```

Take a look at the documentation for details.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
editList = {(EditText) findViewById(R.id.decValue), ...};
```

with :

```
editList = new EditText[]{(EditText) findViewById(R.id.decValue), ...};
```

In your first example the initialization of the array was correct, but there are no `EditText` till `onCreate` method is called.
In the second case, you were almost correct, but you were doing the array [initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938101/how-to-initialize-an-array-in-java) bad.

Answer (score 0):

Define your class variables inside the class (but not inside any method!)

Then you assign the variables in your `onCreate()` method (for example).

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    EditText evDecValue;
    EditText evOctValue;
    EditText evHexValue;
    ...
    ... 
    ...
    EditText evBinValue;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        evDecValue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.decValue);
        evOctValue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.octValue);
        evHexValue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.hexValue);
        ...
        ...
        ...
        evHexValue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.binValue);
    }
}
```

Please note that "..."  is for you to fill in with the other `EditViews`. I was to lazy to type them all.

I believe you will be more satisfied assigning each `EditView` to its own variable. It is cleaner syntax and you will know exactly which `EditView` you are accessing. Otherwise you would need to know which `EditView` was assigned to `editList[1]`.