# Initializing Spinner array

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I tried initializing like a regular array of primitive objects.

```
public class AnotherActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    public Spinner [] jobSites;
    Spinner x, y;

    @Override
    protected void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

         x= findViewById(R.id.job1);
         y= findViewById(R.id.job2);
         jobSites = {x,y};
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change line `jobSites = {x,y};` to `jobSites = new Spinner[]{x,y}`. Here you jobSites acts as reference to array which is null initially. Without creating an array you are trying to jobSites refer something...

> Kindly learn basics of array initialization in java. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938101/how-to-initialize-an-array-in-java) might help you.