# how to initialize Matrix object

Tags: java, matrix

I create a class called MATRIX which has one attribute

```
int [][] _matrix;
```

In another class I create an obj of type MATRIX:

```
Matrix newMatrix=new Matrix();
```

I want to initialize  the obj like in this example:

```
int [][] a={{1,2,3}, {2,2,4}}
```

I try to write

```
newMatrix._matrix={{1,2,3}, {2,2,4}}
```

and I got a syntax error.

What did I've done wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if possible. This way, it's more likely volunteers on SO can help you.

Comment: note: `int [][] a={{1,2,3}, {2,2,4}}` is actually a shortcut for `int [][] a= new int[][] {{1,2,3}, {2,2,4}}` - this is only allowed when declaring an array, not in an assignment

Answer (score 5):

Considering your basic example,

```
public class Matrix {

    int[][] _matrix;
}
```

You can initialize matrix as follows

```
public class Caller {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Matrix m = new Matrix();
        m._matrix = new int[][]{{1,2,3}, {2,2,4}};
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't down-voted, but.... this initialization `int [][] a={{1,2,3}, {2,2,4}}` [is correct](https://ideone.com/6RmRij) too.

Answer (score 0):

```java
newMatrix._matrix = new int[][] {{1,2,3}, {2,2,4}};
```

The reason your code does not compile is because you are missing the `new int[][]` statement. It is required in a line, where you want to use a shortcut array initializer. See this question: [How to initialize an array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938101/how-to-initialize-an-array-in-java/1938302)

Comment: Please explain how this fixes OP's problem.

Comment: It fixes: "I try to write newMatrix._matrix={{1,2,3}, {2,2,4}} and i got a syntax error.", because that syntax error is founded in a missing new int-array statement. The compiler cannot resolve the double-brackets as array initializers. I was writing that in my answer, just now :)

Comment: Then a simple "you're missing the `new int[][]` syntax" goes a long way in helping OP understand what they did wrong. And no problem, just wanted to make the answer more effective for them.

Comment: I'm not mad at you; I just write [assertively](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assertiveness) when on this site.

Comment: Ah, got it. I misunderstood the initial question 'Please explain how this fixes OP's problem.' as a bit offended. Maybe 'Please elaborate your answer'? :)

Comment: @lealceldeiro `int [][] a={{1,2,3}, {2,2,4}};` is correct, but not `matrix._matrix = {{1,2,3}, {2,2,4}};`, because the compiler requires the `int [][]` to be inline. For example, `Object a = { 1, 2, 3 };` is not allowed, but both `Object a = new int[]{ 1, 2, 3 };` and `int[] a = { 1, 2, 3 };` are.

Answer (score 0):

newMatrix._matrix={{1,2,3}, {2,2,4}} is not allowed according to [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6). I have added alternate way to achieve the same results.

```
package com.psl;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    matrix._matrix = new int[][]{{1,2,3}, {2,2,4}};


}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This way you can initialize your matrix

```
class Matrix {
    int[][] _matrix;

    public int [][] get_matrix(){
        return this._matrix;
    }

    public void set_matrix(int [][] a){
        this._matrix = a;
    }
}


public class Test {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.set_matrix(new int[][]{{1,2,3}, {2,2,4}});
        System.out.print(matrix.get_matrix());
    }
}
```

OR you can create a static properties in class and then initialize with class name