# String list in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

I have a very simple question in java

below is my code I am trying to declare a string as given but its showing error in java.

```java
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class Testjava {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         // one easy string, one that's a little bit harder
        String[] testStrings = {"datefrom":"2018-03-19T23:59:59Z","dateto":"2018-03-22T23:59:59Z", "name" : ["flow"]};

          String encodedString;
          for (String s : testStrings)
          {
        try {
            encodedString = URLEncoder.encode(s, "UTF-8");

          System.out.format("'%s'\n", encodedString);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }




    }
}
```

Can someone tell me how to declare this string value?

Comment: Why the colons? And why that statement before imports?

Comment: What is it that you want? A string or an array of strings? It's not clear.

Comment: You are trying to declare a JSON part as a String array; this is not possible as you do it.

Comment: please see the updated one.String[] testStrings is what i need to pass. where its erroring bec of the special chara.

Comment: Your code does not even compile.

Comment: This does not compile. That is not a valid array initializer. And which one is that "special chara"?

Comment: yes its not even cmpiling... see i want to encode the value given in testStrings .. how i can acheive this :(

Comment: You seem to be confusing JavaScript syntax with Java syntax. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938101/how-to-initialize-an-array-in-java/1938302.

Comment: @TTT I think you confuse "encoding" with "valid java syntax"

Comment: By the way, you might want to learn about handling a time range using the Half-Open approach where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your String array is incorrect. You need to escape the " characters.

Try:

```
 String[] testStrings = {"datefrom\":\"2018-03-19T23:59:59Z","dateto'\":\"2018-03-22T23:59:59Z", "name\" : [\"flow\"]"};
```

Comment: you are amazinggg... it worked.. Thanksss a lot !!

Comment: @TTT accept the answer then ;-p

Comment: ahh.. I have been looking for voting option. i got it now. done. thanksss