# Can someone help me resolve the errors I have with my code?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I've been working on this from quite some time now and am getting frustrated with the errors I am getting I hope someone out there can help me fix at least some of these or put me in the right direction. My errors start with **//. I tried to look up my questions already and could find nothing that truly helped me but I know i'll find someone on here who can this is why i'm posting.

````
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Math;

public class TestBoxBiggest
{
 public static void main(String[]args)
 {
  //10 random Integers
   Random n=new Random();
   Integer[] x= new Integer(10);**//error:cannot convert from java.lang.Integer to java.lang.Integer[]**
   for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
   {
    x[i]=n.nextInt(100); 
    System.out.println("The Integers are :\n"+x[i]);
   }
   SelectionSort.sort(x,10);
   System.out.println("The greatest Integer is:" +x);

   //10 random Doubles\

   Double[] d=new Double(10.0);**//cannot convert from java.lang.Double to  java.lang.Double[]**
   for (double k=0.0;k<10.0;k++)
   {
    d[k]=Math.random(1.0);**//cannot convert from double to int & the method random() in the type java.lang.Math is not applicable for the arguments (double)**
    System.out.println("The Doubles are:\n"+d[k]);**//cannot convert from double to int**
   }
   SelectionSort.sort(d,10);
   System.out.println("The greatest Double is:" +d);



  //5 Random box objects
   Random r=new Random();
   Box[]b=new Box[5];
   for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
   {
    int length=r.nextInt(30)+1; 
    int width=r.nextInt(30)+1;
    int height=r.nextInt(30)+1;
    b[i]=new Box(length,width,height);
    System.out.println("The boxes are: "+b[i]);
   }
   SelectionSort.sort(b,5);
   System.out.println("Boxes sorted by volume:\n");
   for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
   {
    System.out.println(b[i]+ "Volume: "+b[i].volume()); 
   }

   //5 String names
   String[] names={"Bobby","Freddie","John","Ralph","Usman"};
   System.out.println("The Strings are: "+names);

   Biggest.sort(names,names.length);//String implements comparable  **//the method sort(java.lang.String[],int) is undefined for the type Biggest**

   System.out.println("Sorted Strings\n");
   for(int i=0;i<names.length;i++)
   {
    System.out.println(names[i]); 
   }
 }
}```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to initialize an array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938101/how-to-initialize-an-array-in-java)

Comment: new Integer(10) creates one Integer object with a value of 10. new Integer[10] creates an array of 10 Integer objects.

Answer (score 0):

Your errors occur because you didn't understand the concept of arrays in Java and your syntax of initializing them is wrong. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1938117/4879856) post to learn how to initialize an array.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem 1.**

```
Integer[] x= new Integer(10);**//error:cannot convert from java.lang.Integer to java.lang.Integer[]**
```

Here problem is that you are trying to assign an object of non-array type `new Integer(10)` to a variable of array type `Integer[]`.

A correct ways to do is as follows:

```
Integer[] x = new Integer[] { 10 };
Integer[] y = { 10 };
int[] z = { 10 };
```

**Problem 2.**

Same applies to the next error

```
Double[] d=new Double(10.0);**//cannot convert from java.lang.Double to  java.lang.Double[]**
```

You need

```
Double[] d = { 10.0 };
```

**Problem 3.**

```
d[k]=Math.random(1.0);**//cannot convert from double to int & the method random() in the type java.lang.Math is not applicable for the arguments (double)**
System.out.println("The Doubles are:\n"+d[k]);**//cannot convert from double to int**
```

Here variable `k` is of type `double`. Arrays expect `int` types as an index. Simply change the type of `k` from double to `int`

Another problem is that `Math.random()` does not expect any parameters. Simply call it without passing any parameters and it will return a random value between 0 and 1

**Problem 4.**

```
Biggest.sort(names,names.length);//String implements comparable  **//the method sort(java.lang.String[],int) is undefined for the type Biggest**
```

Here hard to say what's the exact problem without knowing the signature of `Biggest.sort` method