# Encountered a java identifie expected error

Tags: java

I am running a program test and Java kept on showing me this error message :

```
java: <identifier> expected
```

Can you please tell me what is wrong with my code?

```
package com.Benjamin;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String wordListOne = "24/7", "wine", "shoes", "cake", "car";
        String wordListTwo = "cat", "Islam", "boat", "lake", "puppy";
        String wordListThree = "ballon", "football", "joy", "pie", "war";
        int oneLength = wordListOne.length;
        int twoLength = wordListTwo.length;
        int threeLength = wordListThree.length;
        int rand1 = (int) (Math.random() * oneLength);
        int rand2 = (int) (Math.random() * twoLength);
        int rand3 = (int) (Math.random() * threeLength);
        String phrase = wordListOne [rand1] + " " + wordListTwo[rand2] + " " + wordListThree[rand3] + "." ;
        System.out.println(phrase);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect this line to do? `String wordListOne = "24/7", "wine", "shoes", "cake", "car";`

Comment: [How to initialize an array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938101/how-to-initialize-an-array-in-java)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to initialize an array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938101/how-to-initialize-an-array-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

String wordListOne = "24/7", "wine", "shoes", "cake", "car";

String wordListTwo = "cat", "Islam", "boat", "lake", "puppy";

String wordListThree = "ballon", "football", "joy", "pie", "war";

You're trying to assign multiple strings to a String variable, a String variable can only contain only one string, between quotes.

Perhaps you might wanna use an array of strings: [check here](https://www.journaldev.com/17809/java-string-array)