# Why does this line produce a nullpointer? Java 15

Tags: java

The following two lines:

```
   Boolean visitedAlphabet[] = new Boolean[26];
   Arrays.stream(visitedAlphabet).anyMatch(e -> e != true);
```

Produce a nullpointer, the second line to be specific:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Boolean.booleanValue()" because "<parameter1>" is null
```

Could you please tell me why this happens?

Comment: The Boolean objects in the array have not been initialized?  Try logging the value of `visitedAlphabet[0]` after creation

Comment: Change it to `boolean[]` and they'll default to `false`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT - Adding John Bollinger's excellent comment snippet -

Because `e` is null and the runtime is trying to "unbox" it to a primitive `boolean`.

You can either do `(e != null && e != true)` or `!Boolean.TRUE.equals(e)` or initialize your array:

Initialize an array stuff:

[How to initialize an array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938101/how-to-initialize-an-array-in-java)

Boxing and unboxing:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

Comment: Or `!Boolean.TRUE.equals(e)`.  That handles nulls naturally.